# Query to show table. See message

Tags: sql

FAMILY

```
ID  NAME            P_ID
1   Grnd Fath   NULL
2   Fath            1
3   Brot1           2
4   Brot2           2
5   Son_brot1   3
6   Son_brot2   4
```

How can I find below records from above table?

```
NAME          PARENT NAME
Fath          Grnd Fath
Brot1         Fath
Brot2         Fath
Son_brot1     Brot1
Son_brot2     Brot2
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Please mention which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f.NAME, f2.NAME as PARENT_NAME
FROM FAMILY f
   INNER JOIN FAMILY f2 ON f.P_ID=f2.ID
```